# Custom Writer and Accessors using JSONB with Mobility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mobility

Mobility Version: 0.4.2 / Rails Version: 5.2.0.rc1

In a Rails app using Mobility I have a model structure that looks like this:

```
create_table :settings do |t|
  t.string :type
  t.jsonb :values, null: false, default: {}
  t.timestamps
end

add_index  :site_settings, :values, using: :gin
```

And my model looks like this:

```
class Setting < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  translates :values
end
```

In the values column I save multiple value settings, for example:

`Setting.create(values: { setting_1: 'test', setting_2: 'test2' })`

Until here Mobility is working as expected and is saving the hash in the proper locale.

But now I would like to provide convenient methods for other developers to write and read values, for example:

```
ss = Setting.new
ss.setting_1 = 'test'
ss.setting_2 = 'test2'
ss.save
```

and read methods:

`Setting.last.setting_1 => 'test'`

I have tried using `store_accessor` and even with custom accessors but I can not get working properly Mobility using `store_accessor` or other custom methods.

Any help?

---

Mobility configuration:

```
Mobility.configure do |config|
  config.default_backend = :jsonb
  config.accessor_method = :translates
  config.query_method = :i18n
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Setting < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  translates :values, presence: false, default: {}

  def setting_1
    values["setting_1"]
  end

  def setting_1=(value)
    values["setting_1"] = value
  end

  def setting_2
    values["setting_2"]
  end

  def setting_2=(value)
    values["setting_2"] = value
  end

  # etc...
end
```

I disabled the presence plugin, which otherwise would turn an empty hash into `nil`, and set the default value to `{}` to avoid a nil key error.

Getting dirty tracking to work I leave as an exercise to the reader ;)

Comment: It doesn't work, that assign the attributes correctly to the values hash but then when the record is saved in the database the values are saved as nil

Comment: In fact the behaviour is really weird: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8ab1bd2b738e3fa6daab0a395eabeeaa

Comment: Sorry that's not what I see with a simple model and the setup above. You'll have to provide more detail, but there's nothing magical, just setting hash values.